# How do you export forum topics from one drupal installation to another?

Tags: features, nodes, importing-exporting

I have tried to export a list of forum topics and/or containers from my development environment to production using features, strongarm, migrate, node_export and bulk_export. So far none have worked. Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible via contrib modules?

Answer (score 0):

If your environments can communicate via rsync then use
`drush sql-sync`

Check the syntax [www.drushcommands.com/drush-7x/sql/sql-sync](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-7x/sql/sql-sync) to see how to pass a list of tables via the tables-list parameter.

else just use mysqldump.

Comment: I would love to be able to use drush sql-sync and rync to exclusively manage the deployment workflow but it is not feasible at this time. currently our configuration management is captured in features and pushed via drush rsync. the nodes and users tables vary drastically so sql dumps are ill advised. any other options? is there a list of tables that can capture all of the forum data??

Comment: If you have the full list of tables, a full dump of these will do ? Have you had a look at the forum.install for the forum module to see if it creates tables or node types or something else ?